# Handle exception in between loading and displaying data

Tags: c#, exception

I had this situation not sure how to best handle this. Input would be appreciated. Imagine I Have such method:

```
void loaddata()
{
    try
    {
        // EXTRA: I also want to skip below SaveSomething if there was exeption
        // last time I called DecryptAndloadXMLdata. This may happen
        // if user calls loaddata twice. This is exaclty similar situation
        // as app quitting just it happens is user calls loaddata twice
        // and during first call there was exception say with DecryptAndloadXMLdata
        Savesomething(listOfObjects, xmlPath);//save old data first
        xmlPath = newValue;

        // some operations

        xmlDoc = DecryptAndloadXMLdata(xmlPath);

        // some other operations- populate List with data from above XML file
        listOfObjects.Add(objectFromXML);
        // Here also possibly modify contents of listOfObjects elements
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        xlmPath="";
    }
}
```

Now the thing is when app is quiting I have such feature
to automatically save the List object populated in above
method to a file. Like:

```
void whenAppisQuitting()
{
    Savesomething(listOfObjects, xmlPath);
}
```

But the problem is. Imagine  `xmlDoc = loadXMLdata();` throws in above method. What will happen is the List I mentioned won't be populated and when app is quitting empty elements (e.g. empty `listOfObjects`) will be written to `xmlPath` - thus damaging my original file because there was unrelated exception say due to encryption in `loadXMLData` method.

I hope I have made my issue clear. What is the way to deal with such situations? For example what I did you can see I set `xmlPath` to empty in `catch` - thus in case of any exception I considered data was not loaded successfully - hence now on application exit I can be calm because nothing will be written to file because its `xmlPath =""`. Is it reasonable way to solve this issue?

Getting bit confused because this kind of issues now raise error handling to different level - I need to account for all possible kind of failures?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the way to deal with such situations?

I would set a flag indicating there was an error when parsing. Setting the path to `string.Empty` can lead to confusion (IMO). Perhaps an empty string could be a possible value bring passed to your method.

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Log
    IsParsingSuccessful = false;
}
```

And look upon that flag when you want to write:

```
void AppIsQuitting()
{
    if (IsParsingSuccessful)
    {
        SaveSomething(listOfObjects, xmlPath);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you have good point. Just one more thing. You can see I can call SaveSomething even without app quiting - in loaddata method before LoadDecryptXML call. Now, if there was exception from previous call to LoadDecryptXML - similarly to the app quiting example I don't want the SaveSomething to occur inside the loaddata method... how/where to set the flags now?

Comment: so this way basically even if there is *single* exception in between loaddata call - I need to consider the operation invalid and cancel all future writes

Comment: You can check on the `IsParsingSuccessful` before calling `Save`, or you can make `Save` check the flag.

Comment: The flag indicates the parsing of the latest value. If it failed, all methods should be aware of it. You can wrap it in some sort of `ValidateParsing` method which each method calls before executing the operation.

Comment: @ Yuval Itzchakov: Aha ok so  basically I would put that check also inside loaddata() method right? Before calling the Save?

Comment: @user Yes. You would.

Comment: I just had issues where to set that flag to true/false - and what to make its initial value etc ..

Comment: but now with  xlmPath=""; is also seems to work; but thanks for input. So you think your approach would solve my issue? Even if I want to restrict writing inside loaddata()? Like I updated my question now.

Comment: @User You can make the initial value whatever you want. You can assume a parse will usually succeed and set the initial value to `true` and only when an error occurs set it to `false`.

Comment: OK thank I think you fully understood my problem right? And you think that solves my issue? Even when restricting write at two places - old file inside loaddata and during app quiting? I will get back to this question also later just now I can hardly concentrate. So if you think this approach solves my issue just tell me last time. But it is still tricky now because even if there was some simple exception you need to set IsParsingSuccessful = false ....

Comment: @User You can catch a more specific exception, like `XmlException` of some sort to indicate there was a problem. Setting the flag in a general `Exception` clause might not be the right thing. I'm not familiar with the details of your code, so I can only give you an outsiders advice. I think the flag would be a good starting point for what you need.

Comment: OK thanks I see what you mean with more specific exceptions etc. but catching in general exception might also be ok for me.. it seems like atomic operation now - it is successfull only if no exception occured in between. Just like I said I got confused when I needed to restrict write also in loaddata() method... I started doubting where to set that flag etc.. I would set that flag to true only at the end of try block right? before catch line?

Comment: I guess I Must set it to true initially and at the end of try method - when all operation inside try complete; and set to false only inside catch

Comment: Where do I set flag IsParsingSuccessful as true?

Comment: You could set it in the class constructor?

Comment: Yes but afterwards? that should not be only place where I set it to true, is it? I think afterwards I should set it to true when all operations in try are done

Comment: @User Everytime you finish parsing an XML, it should be either true or false.

Comment: @ Yuval Itzchakov: Ok I will check it bit later - I think indeed flags in such case is the way to go. btw. did you understand the EXTRA part in my question :)? (sorry for asking too many questions - we may later remove these comments if possible). ps and yes so it means I should set that flag as true after all statements inside try

Answer (score 0):

As a general guidance, you probably should never overwrite files without explicit intent from the user.

As for your error handling, use a simple flag / boolean to indicate valid behavior. Only set that flag to true after everything is processed and only if that flag is true, save the contents to the file.

Comment: yeah in my case basically I also have flag but *xmlPath* acts as a flag right? if it is empty I don't write anything to file. Is that what you mean? Where/how would you put those flags in above code? 
Also another tricky thing is before loading and decrypting that file - I had code before it to save old file - so if I used flag - it would be set to false at that moment, hence the old file would also not be saved

Comment: using `xmlPath` as your flag will work, but has it's downside. You lose the value in case you want to retry later, and it makes the code less readable than a variable called `IsDataValid`.

Comment: why I lose value if I want to retry later?

Comment: because you've set it to an empty string... suppose you got the path from user input, and you want to try again automatically every minute. If you clear your variable, you won't be able to do so without asking the user for the path again.

Comment: path comes from OpenFileDialog